# Accessing body string of an OkHttp Response twice results in IllegalStateException: closed

Tags: android, okhttp

I implement my http calls via the OkHttp library. Everything works fine, but I noticed that, when I access the body as a string of the response twice an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown. 
That is, I do (for example): `Log.d("TAG", response.body().string())` and after that I actually want to use that string like `processResponse(response.body().string())`. But that second call throws the exception with the message `closed`.

How can it be possible that accessing a string twice results in a failure? I want to process that response without the need to add a wrapper/dummy object just for saving some values (like header, body, statuscode).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `string` method on the response will read the input (network) stream and convert it into a string. So it dynamically builds the string and returns it to you. The second time you call it, the network stream has already been consumed and is no longer available.

You should save the result of `string` into a String variable, and then access it as many times as needed.

Comment: I was hoping that I could just reuse that `Response` object. Before using OkHttp I returned a custom ApiResult object where I just saved all relevant information, but its just a duplicate IMO.

Comment: maybe you should checkout this [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240) on github.

Comment: I see your point. I guess they just wanted to keep it as low level as possible without caching the result that may never be called again

Comment: @penkzhou well, that issue just states that you cannot use it twice. No futher information. But still, thanks

Comment: What about saving it as an InputStream?

Comment: I was having the same problem. Although this implementation has its justifications, it's non-intuitive to developers without trawling the code in okhttp3

Answer (score 104):

**Update:**

As [mugwort points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53060923/2011622) there is a simpler, more lightweight API available now ([see GitHub issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2869)):

```
String responseBodyString = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE).string();
Log.d("TAG", responseBodyString);
```

**Original Answer:**

For explanation of the issue see [Greg Ennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922818/2011622).

However, if you can not easily pass the result in a variable, but still need to access the response body twice you have another option:

Clone the buffer before reading it. By that the original buffer is neither emptied nor closed. See this snippet:

```
ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
BufferedSource source = responseBody.source();
source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); // request the entire body.
Buffer buffer = source.buffer();
// clone buffer before reading from it
String responseBodyString = buffer.clone().readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
Log.d("TAG", responseBodyString);
```

This approach is used in [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.13.x/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L248-L276) in project [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) by square themselves.

Comment: thanks a lot man. Really needed this way other wise i would have needed to change it in like 20-30 places :)

Answer (score 12):

```
ResponseBody body = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE);
String content = body.string();
//do something
```

this code get the response body and won't consume the buffer. it is a new api added in [this issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1740)

Comment: documentation says: "Most applications should set a modest limit on `byteCount`, such as 1 MiB."

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a little on the answers of [user2011622](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33862068/984830) and [Greg Ennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922818/984830), I created a method which helps you to create a complete clone of the body, allowing you to consume each copy of the body separately. I use this method myself with Retrofit2

```
/**
 * Clones a raw buffer so as not to consume the original
 * @param rawResponse the original {@link okhttp3.Response} as returned
 *                    by {@link Response#raw()}
 * @return a cloned {@link ResponseBody}
 */
private ResponseBody cloneResponseBody(okhttp3.Response rawResponse) {
    final ResponseBody responseBody = rawResponse.body();
    final Buffer bufferClone = responseBody.source().buffer().clone();
    return ResponseBody.create(responseBody.contentType(), responseBody.contentLength(), bufferClone);
}
```

Comment: Just call the method with the response, you'll get another copy of the response body back but the original will remain available (open)

Comment: look in the sources and implement the same thing i have for prior (new isntance from cloned source), i'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 2):

BTW in addition to Greg Ennis' answer I can tell what onetime this happened to me when I forgot response.body().string() in the watch window. So under the debugger the body was reading into the watch and the network stream was closed after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE);` to buffer the entire response in memory and get a lightweight copy of it. It'll be much less wasteful. [See this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2869).

Comment: documentation says: "Most applications should set a modest limit on `byteCount`, such as 1 MiB."