# Can't get OkHttp's response.body.toString() to return a string

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to get some json data using OkHttp and can't figure out why when i try logging the `response.body().toString()` what i get is `Results:﹕ com.squareup.okhttp.Call$RealResponseBody@41c16aa8`

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(BaseUrl);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header(/****/)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        Response response = call.execute();

        **//for some reason this successfully prints out the response**
        System.out.println("YEAH: " + response.body().string());

        if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i("Response code", " " + response.code());
        }

        Log.i("Response code", response.code() + " ");
        String results = response.body().toString();

        Log.i("OkHTTP Results: ", results);
```

[image: Log]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. How do i get the response string?

Comment: Maybe it`s a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java)

Comment: You just print an object and your trace confirm it.

Comment: read the doc. the method you are looking for is `string`

Comment: val responseBodyString = response.body()!!.string()
        response = response.newBuilder()
            .body(ResponseBody.create(responseBody?.contentType(), responseBodyString.toByteArray()))
            .build()

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824088/12272687

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just in case someone bumps into the same weird thing as I have. I run my code during development in **Debug Mode** and apparently since OKHttp 2.4

> ..the response body is a one-shot value that may be consumed only once

So when in debug there is a call "behind the scene" from the inspector and the body is always empty. See: https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody.html

Comment: Dead link. Use this one ==> http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Response.html

Comment: how do you call `.string()` without consuming response body?

Comment: Not sure if you can call .string() without consuming the response body, but as a workaround, but you can follow the pattern that okhttp's logging interceptor use to do this: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L237-L266

Comment: It means that we can't debug Okhttp response body

Comment: You can print the response body to Log with debug disabled

Comment: What a wicked behavior! I know how unhelpful this sort of comments is, want to thank you nevertheless

Comment: @OdedRegev life savior!

Comment: If you want to access the response body multiple times (e.g. when debugging) see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33862068/2011622

Answer (score 310):

You have use `.string()` function to print the response in `System.out.println()`. But at last in `Log.i()` you are using `.toString()`.

So please use `.string()` on response body to print and get your request's response, like:

```
response.body().string();
```

**NOTE:**

1. `.toString()`: This returns your object in string format.
2. `.string()`: This returns your response.

I think this solve your problem... Right.

Comment: No more string() function, what now?

Comment: @eCDroid "_No more string() function_" Are you sure?

Comment: As per documentation ` Closes ResponseBody automatically.` You need to keep in mind that you wont be able to read response after calling this method

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed got error

Answer (score 21):

The `response.body.string()` can be consumed only once.
Please use as below:

```
String responseBodyString = response.body.string();
```

Use the responseBodyString as needed in your application.

Comment: This may trigger an **OutOfMemoryError** for a large response (i.e. zip file)

Comment: Typo with comma inside your 1st line's code-span, should be `response.body.string()`. The hint in your code-block should be out-commented, e.g. prefix with `//`.

Answer (score 3):

Following is my modified CurlInterceptor. Check the end of the intercept function where I m recreating the Response object after consuming the old Response.

> var responseBodyString = responseBody?.string()
>
> response = response.newBuilder()
> .body(
> ResponseBody.create(
> responseBody?.contentType(),
> responseBodyString.toByteArray()
> )
> )
> .build()

```
class CurlInterceptor: Interceptor
{

    var gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    Timber.d(" **** ->>Request to server -> ****")

    val request = chain.request()
    var response = chain.proceed(request)

    var curl = "curl -v -X  ${request.method()}"

    val headers = request.headers()

    for ( i in 0..(headers.size() -1) ){
        curl = "${curl} -H \"${headers.name(i)}: ${headers.value(i)}\""
    }

    val requestBody = request.body()
    if (requestBody != null) {
        val buffer = Buffer()
        requestBody.writeTo(buffer)
        var charset: Charset =
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")
        curl = "${curl} --data '${buffer.readString(charset).replace("\n", "\\n")}'"
    }

    Timber.d("$curl ${request.url()}")
    Timber.d("response status code ${response.code()} message: ${response.message()}")

    
    dumbHeaders(response)

    var responseBody = response?.body()

    if(responseBody != null )
    {
        var responseBodyString = responseBody?.string()

            response = response.newBuilder()
                .body(
                    ResponseBody.create(
                        responseBody?.contentType(),
                        responseBodyString.toByteArray()
                    )
                )
                .build()


        responseBodyString = gson.toJson(responseBodyString)

        Timber.d("response json -> \n $responseBodyString")

    }

    Timber.d(" **** << Response from server ****")

    return response
}



fun dumbHeaders(response: Response) {
    try {
        if (response.headers() != null) {

            for (headerName in response.headers().names()) {
                for (headerValue in response.headers(headerName)) {
                    Timber.d("Header $headerName : $headerValue")
                }
            }
        }
    }
catch (ex: Exception){}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that a response can potentially produce an `OutOfMemoryError` in cases of large files, you can instead "peek" the body with the number of bytes and call the `string()` method.

Note that this will consume the body.

`response.peekBody(500).string());`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using .toString() which returns an object

```
String results = response.body().toString();
```

you can use

```
String results = response.body().string();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Call call = client.newCall(request);
   return call.execute().body().string();
```

we can get response as a return fromby these

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to change it like that  for example:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put("type", type);
                data.put("message", message);
                data.put("title", title);
                data.put("image_url", imageUrl);
                data.put("uid",uid);
                data.put("id", id);
                data.put("message_id", messageId);
                data.put("display_name", displayName);
                root.put("data", data);
                root.put("registration_ids", new JSONArray(receipts));
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, root.toString());
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL)
                        .post(body)
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + serverKey)
                        .build();
                Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();
                String result = response.body().string();
                Log.d(TAG, "Result: " + result);
                return result;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Exception -> "+ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the response object after consuming the string

val responseBodyString = response.body()!!.string()

response = response.newBuilder()
.body(ResponseBody.create(responseBody?.contentType(), responseBodyString.toByteArray()))
.build()

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Programmers I am here for you

```
 response.body?.charStream()?.readText()?.let { 
                        //Where it refers to Response string
                        callBack.onAPISuccess(it)
                    }
```

Here you can not use .toString() function and .string() function is not available in Kotlin than you can user charStream() and than convert that charStream into readText() but you have to unwrap the whole value before passing it.But it will never create problem.

I have not explored these charStream() and readText() functions in java but I think it should be there and you can use this in java if these functions are available because I just got to know that java has deprecated the .string() function.