# How to get a raw Retrofit response string?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am working on Retrofit, but I am stuck on one thing: how do I get the raw JSON on the response body.

```
public interface ViewMenuItems {
  @GET
  Call<ResponseBody> listRepos(@Url String url);
}

ViewMenuItems viewMenuItems = ApiClient.getClient().create(ViewMenuItems.class);
  Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = viewMenuItems.listRepos(Webservices.MERCHANT + merchantId + Webservices.MENU_ITEMS_LASTMODIFIED);

       responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
          Log.d("MenuItems", "Response :: " + response.body().toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
         Log.d("MenuItems", "Exception :: " + t.toString());
       }
 });
```

But in the "MenuItems" log I am not getting the JSON response, it's coming something like this

```
MenuItems: Response :: retrofit2.Response@e292dd4
```

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Have you tried to call `body().string()` instead of `body().toString()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get OkHttp's response.body.toString() to return a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300359/cant-get-okhttps-response-body-tostring-to-return-a-string)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to use `body().string()` instead of `body().toString()`

Comment: @Salem How do I parse the Json object and Json arrays which is present in that string

Comment: @Prabs You cna use any library of your choice: [gson](https://github.com/google/gson), Jackson or even the default JSONObject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/1205368

Comment: @Salem I've done this - 
`JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());` then use that Json object to fetch arrays and objects within it

Comment: @AhmedMousa I think it's removed in Retrofit2

Comment: @AhmedMousa try raw().body().string()

Comment: I had to cast it, otherwise it assumes my dto type
 String body = ((ResponseBody) response.body()).string();

Answer (score 5):

Use `Call<JSONObject>`. That way you don't even need to include any of [retrofit converters](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters) in your project.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question. Plus, what if the deserialization of the JSON was actually wanted?

Comment: True, I didn't spot the `on response body` part of the question. Although, this is still valid, for the deserialization one can use any method inside the response callback, although I admit that most of the times it's not the best idea.