# Java declare object but assign it inside 'if' won't work

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm declaring an object like this:

```
Response getMessagesResponse;
        if (page == 0) {
            getMessagesResponse = myRequest.newCall(getMessagesRequest).execute();
            System.out.println("response "+getMessagesResponse.body().string());
```

The code above will print an empty string, no matter how times I run it. Now, if I assign and call the object at the same line, like this:

```
if (page == 0) {
            Response a = sisgradRequest.newCall(getMessagesRequest).execute();
            System.out.println("response "+a.body().string());
```

it will work. Why? I've always did things like this in java and had no problem. The newCall method here is from the OkHttp3 java library.

UPDATE:

before System.out.println() in the first code, I had this line:

```
        this.magicalNumber = getMagicalNumber(getMessagesResponse.body().string());
```

turns out that if I put System.out.println() before it, I get the print. If i put after it, I don't get it. Why? Maybe because jSoup inside getMagicalNumber processes the data and then erases it from the main object?

Comment: Perhaps `myRequest` isn't returning data, but `sisgradRequest` is?

Comment: More context might be helpful too.

Comment: @azurefrog they're calls for the same request, and also I checked the header content-lenght and its huge

Comment: @lucasvw hmmm, they're calls for the same request, inside a method that's called by main(). I was trying to print the object outside the if but it won't work. I tried then inside if, won't work too. However, System.out.println(getMessagesRequest.request()) will print data related to the call :c

Comment: Something else is up.  Have you tried debugging?

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Possibly it's a stream that's being consumed somewhere in the internals.

Comment: perhaps getMagicalNumber() is never returning, or executes an exit() somewhere, or is throwing an exception? Run it in a debugger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Taylor commented, the `ResponseBody` is a stream which can only be consumed once. From the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html),

> **The response body can be consumed only once.**
>
> This class may be used to stream very large responses. For example, it is possible to use this class to read a response that is larger than the entire memory allocated to the current process. It can even stream a response larger than the total storage on the current device, which is a common requirement for video streaming applications.
>
> Because this class does not buffer the full response in memory, the application may not re-read the bytes of the response. Use this one shot to read the entire response into memory with `bytes()` or `string()`. Or stream the response with either `source()`, `byteStream()`, or `charStream()`.

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307866/1371329