# Result disappeared in retrofit 2.4.0

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to use retrofit for fetching data from my server. My server send data as a string json.
I create a server like this:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.100.73/ChartReport/Service1.svc/";


    static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

And then i have created client like blow:

```
public interface IReportCLient {
    @POST("json/GetDataReport")
    Call<ResponseBody> getReporst();
}
```

And I have used into my activity :

```
IReportCLient service = ServiceGenerator.createService(IReportCLient.class);
Call<ResponseBody> reporst = service.getReporst();

reporst.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            JsonObject post = new JsonObject().get(response.body().string()).getAsJsonObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

When I run my app in debug mode for first time i fetch my data by this command:
`response.body().string()`
but immediately my result is null when i run `response.body().string()` again??
[image]

What is happens?

Comment: post the the response

Comment: @ALTegani what does mean? do you mean put response to my question?

Comment: no imean the response  send by your server

Comment: @ALTegani response is sended by server.I am sure 100%.you can see in picture `GetDataReportResult`

Answer (score 1):

`string()` method can only be called once on `RequestBody`. So it will return empty string if you try to call it again. This is true for debugging as well. If you try to evaluate expressions `response.body().string()` while debugging, your actual methods will get empty string.

> An HTTP response. Instances of this class are not immutable: the
>   response body is a one-shot value that may be consumed only once and
>   then closed. All other properties are immutable.
>   https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html

Read this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307866/6168272

This is how I get `JsonObject` from my response object. You can give it a try.

```
private JSONObject parseJsonFromResponse(Response response) {
            ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
            if (responseBody != null) {
                try {
                    return new JSONObject(responseBody.string());
                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new JSONObject();
                }
            } else return new JSONObject();
        }
```

Comment: In any case if i not use debugging mode, i got error on `new JsonObject().get(response.body().string()).getAsJsonObject();` i got `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.gson.JsonObject com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject()' on a null object reference`

Comment: That means you `JsonObject` is null because `JsonObject().get(responseBody)` returned null.

Comment: Of course but for a little time it is not .. you casn see in picture that i sended

Comment: `response.body().string()` is not null, your `JsonObject().get()` method couldn't parse or something and returned a null object.

Comment: You can modify the else part. I needed an empty `JSONObject`.

Comment: I try your code :`public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = parseErrorJsonFromResponse(response);
                Log.i("======>", "onResponse: " + jsonObject.toString());
            }`   this is logcat output: `.com.chartreport I/======>: onResponse: {}`

Comment: Actually, you have to use `response.body()` instead of `response.errorBody()` in my code.

Comment: You saved my life :) Thank you ... You are rockstar ...I was breaking my head for 2 days to fix this......