# Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'okhttp3': was expecting (JSON String')

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm trying to convert this response from okhttp:

```
[
  {
    "word": "Auricomous",
    "definition": "Having golden or blond hair  ",
    "pronunciation": "Aurikomous"
  }
]
```

using this code:

```
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://random-words-api.vercel.app/word")
                .get()
                .build();

        try (Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            // Get response body

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String responseBody = response.body().toString();
            Root[] root = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, Root[].class);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

DTO:

```
public class Root{
    public String word;
    public String definition;
    public String pronunciation;
}
```

But I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'okhttp3': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@466f95e8"; line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.wordscore.engine.service.generator.WordsGeneratorImpl.generateRandomKeyword(WordsGeneratorImpl.java:47)
    at com.wordscore.engine.processor.KeywordPostJob.execute(KeywordPostJob.java:21)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'okhttp3': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@466f95e8"; line: 1, column: 8]
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get OkHttp's response.body.toString() to return a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300359/cant-get-okhttps-response-body-tostring-to-return-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Issue

The call of `response.body().toString()` method is [inherited from `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true#toString--) class and returns the full class-name with instance's hexadecimal hash-code:

> this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

as `"okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@466f95e8"`.
Because this string is **no valid JSON**, Jackson throws this exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'okhttp3': was expecting (JSON String

This is not what you and Jackson's `ObjectMapper.readValue()` method expected as JSON representation.

#### Solution

Instead use [`response.body().string()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html#string--) method to get the response body's **textual representation** as String (here JSON):

> Returns the response as a string.

See also:

- [Decode an OkHttp JSON Response | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-json-response)

Answer (score 2):

Use `response.body().string()` over `response.body().toString()`, followed by closing the `response.body().close()`

`.toString():` This returns your object in string format.

`.string():` This returns your response.