# Consuming One-Shot ResponseBody from Okhttp causes issues with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using an Retrofit with an Okhttp interceptor in order to detect if my oauth token has expired. If the token has expired, I want to request a new token, try the request again, then send that response to Retrofit.

Here is my interceptor class:

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    // try the request
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    if (response.body().string().contains(Constants.TOKEN_AUTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)) {
        Log.v("retrofit_error", "token expired");

        //get current token, create headers
        OAuthTokenResponse expiredToken = SharedPreferencesUtil.getOAuthToken();

        OAuthTokenResponse newOauthToken = RestClient.getInstance().getTokenService().refreshOauthToken(expiredToken.getRefreshToken());

        //store new token, return
        SharedPreferencesUtil.saveOAuthToken(newOauthToken);

        // create a new request and modify it accordingly using the new token
        Request.Builder newRequestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Authorization");

        Request newRequest = newRequestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", SharedPreferencesUtil.getOAuthToken().getAccessToken()).build();
        // retry the request
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }

    // otherwise just pass the original response on
    return response;
}

}
```

The issue is that calling response.body.string() will consume the ResponseBody due to it being a one-shot value as the Okhttp docs state.

This means that the Response returned at the end of the code will no longer container the body when it is passed off to retrofit. Is there any way that I can consume the body while still returning it with the response?

Thanks!

Comment: you could create a new response with the same body, but I would rather recommend that you use the headers to transmit this kind of information rather than the body.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. I didn't see the ResponseBody builder. I was able to verify that I can use the response.message from the headers instead though as you recommended.

Comment: Alternatively, see this answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922703/accessing-body-string-of-an-okhttp-response-twice-results-in-illegalstateexcepti/27935440#27935440

Comment: Awesome! I searched a while to see if anyone else had this question and I couldn't find that link. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I accomplished this by creating a new response using the [Response.Builder](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Response.Builder.html).  I am able to use `responseBodyString` for my checks; then I return `newResponse`, which is given the body that I consumed.

```
Request request = chain.request();
Response response = chain.proceed(request);

ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
String responseBodyString = response.body().string();
Response newResponse = response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(responseBody.contentType(), responseBodyString.getBytes())).build();

...

return newResponse;
```

Comment: I am getting value something like this. Do you have any idea ?
��������������V*.I,)-V�210�Q�M-.NLOU�R
�HU(�2����J22�r��3���Ԋ�̢�������T�Dbzbf��R-�����U������

Comment: @Ketan Ahir, because as you can see on the `ResponseBody.create`, on the 2nd parameter, he pass the bytes, not the string. You can solve it by removing `.getBytes()` from it.

Comment: @Ketan Ahir, well we don't know if he just removed the `getBytes()` method.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Logging Interceptor
https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor