# OkHttp how to log request body

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using an interceptor, and I would like to log the body of a request I'm making but I can't see any way of doing this.

Is it possible ?

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();

        double time = (t2 - t1) / 1e6d;

        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            Logs.info(String.format("GET " + F_REQUEST_WITHOUT_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), response.code(), response.headers(), response.body().charStream()));
        } else if (request.method().equals("POST")) {
            Logs.info(String.format("POST " + F_REQUEST_WITH_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), request.body(), response.code(), response.headers(), response.body().charStream()));
        } else if (request.method().equals("PUT")) {
            Logs.info(String.format("PUT " + F_REQUEST_WITH_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), request.body().toString(), response.code(), response.headers(), response.body().charStream()));
        } else if (request.method().equals("DELETE")) {
            Logs.info(String.format("DELETE " + F_REQUEST_WITHOUT_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITHOUT_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), response.code(), response.headers()));
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

and the result :

```
POST  [some url] in 88,7ms
    ZoneName: touraine
    Source: Android
    body: retrofit.client.OkClient$1@1df53f05 <-request.body().toString() gives me this, but I would like the content string
    Response: 500
    Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 10:14:22 GMT
    body: [some content]
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Nikola's answer did not work for me. My guess is the implementation of `ByteString#toString()` changed. This solution worked for me:

```
import okio.Buffer;

private static String bodyToString(final Request request){

    try {
        final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
        final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
        return buffer.readUtf8();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        return "did not work";
    }
}
```

From the documentation of `readUtf8()`:

> Removes all bytes from this, decodes them as UTF-8, and returns the string.

which should be what you want.

Comment: Just in case, do you also know how to do this using a Response object ? (copying the response body)

Comment: @MathieudeBrito try `response.body().string()`.

Comment: @aga thanks, but this does not copy the response body, so that when I try to read the body later (after the interceptor), it tells me that responsebody is null and has been read already.

Comment: You have to copy the response using response.newBuilder() and set the string/bytes back in the response body after you have consumed them from the original response. I got the solution from here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306524/consuming-one-shot-responsebody-from-okhttp-causes-issues-with-retrofit

Comment: Is there any specific reason for making all variables **final** in the code?

Comment: Really useful when you are debugging to see the request body!

Answer (score 31):

I tried to comment on the correct answer from @msung, but my reputation isn't high enough.

Here's modification I did to print RequestBody before making it a full request. It works like a charm. Thanks

```
private static String bodyToString(final RequestBody request){
        try {
            final RequestBody copy = request;
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            copy.writeTo(buffer);
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        } 
        catch (final IOException e) {
            return "did not work";
        }
}
```

Comment: its just returning a set of random string. not working

Comment: Have you serialized it in any way?

Comment: no i have not serialized it...can you please edit your answer to do all the stuff in exact way to print the request body

Comment: I'm sorry I don't remember what it prints from memory, I'll add it when I work on that project.

Comment: Why do we need to create copy ?

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT**

Because I see there is still some people interested by this post, here is the final version (until next improvement) of my log interceptor. I hope it will save some of you guys's time.

Please note that this code is using `OkHttp 2.2.0` (and `Retrofit 1.9.0`)

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.*;
import okio.Buffer;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private static final String F_BREAK = " %n";
private static final String F_URL = " %s";
private static final String F_TIME = " in %.1fms";
private static final String F_HEADERS = "%s";
private static final String F_RESPONSE = F_BREAK + "Response: %d";
private static final String F_BODY = "body: %s";

private static final String F_BREAKER = F_BREAK + "-------------------------------------------" + F_BREAK;
private static final String F_REQUEST_WITHOUT_BODY = F_URL + F_TIME + F_BREAK + F_HEADERS;
private static final String F_RESPONSE_WITHOUT_BODY = F_RESPONSE + F_BREAK + F_HEADERS + F_BREAKER;
private static final String F_REQUEST_WITH_BODY = F_URL + F_TIME + F_BREAK + F_HEADERS + F_BODY + F_BREAK;
private static final String F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY = F_RESPONSE + F_BREAK + F_HEADERS + F_BODY + F_BREAK + F_BREAKER;

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    long t2 = System.nanoTime();

    MediaType contentType = null;
    String bodyString = null;
    if (response.body() != null) {
        contentType = response.body().contentType();
        bodyString = response.body().string();
    }

    double time = (t2 - t1) / 1e6d;

    if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
        System.out.println(String.format("GET " + F_REQUEST_WITHOUT_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), response.code(), response.headers(), stringifyResponseBody(bodyString)));
    } else if (request.method().equals("POST")) {
        System.out.println(String.format("POST " + F_REQUEST_WITH_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), stringifyRequestBody(request), response.code(), response.headers(), stringifyResponseBody(bodyString)));
    } else if (request.method().equals("PUT")) {
        System.out.println(String.format("PUT " + F_REQUEST_WITH_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITH_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), request.body().toString(), response.code(), response.headers(), stringifyResponseBody(bodyString)));
    } else if (request.method().equals("DELETE")) {
        System.out.println(String.format("DELETE " + F_REQUEST_WITHOUT_BODY + F_RESPONSE_WITHOUT_BODY, request.url(), time, request.headers(), response.code(), response.headers()));
    }

    if (response.body() != null) {
        ResponseBody body = ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyString);
        return response.newBuilder().body(body).build();
    } else {
        return response;
    }
}


private static String stringifyRequestBody(Request request) {
    try {
        final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
        final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
        return buffer.readUtf8();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        return "did not work";
    }
}

public String stringifyResponseBody(String responseBody) {
    return responseBody;
}
}
```

Comment: If you are able to post the imports  up top, it would be very helpful as there are multiple versions of OKHttp and I am playing guess and check to figure out which ones you have here. Thank you

Comment: Done, hope it helps ;)

Comment: It does, thank you very much for the clarification Mathieu.

Answer (score 12):

With a current version of OkHttp, you can use the [HTTP Logging Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/README.md) and set the level to `BODY`

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
```

With this you cannot granularily configure the output for different HTTP methods, but it also works for other methods that might have a body.

Here an example showing the output of a `PATCH` request (minimally redacted):

```
--> PATCH https://hostname/api/something/123456 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 49
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0Cg==
Accept: application/json

[ { "op": "add", "path": "/path", "value": true }]
--> END PATCH (xx-byte body)
```

As you can see, this also prints out the headers and as the documentation states, you should really take care:

> The logs generated by this interceptor when using the `HEADERS` or `BODY` levels have the potential to leak sensitive information such as "Authorization" or "Cookie" headers and the contents of request and response bodies. This data should only be logged in a controlled way or in a non-production environment.
>
> You can redact headers that may contain sensitive information by calling `redactHeader()`.
>
> ```
> logging.redactHeader("Authorization");
> logging.redactHeader("Cookie");
> ```

Comment: how do I get only [ { "op": "add", "path": "/path", "value": true }] from the request object?

Answer (score 8):

Version that handles requests with or without a body:

```
private String stringifyRequestBody(Request request) {
  if (request.body() != null) {
      try {
          final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
          final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
          copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
          return buffer.readUtf8();
      } catch (final IOException e) {
          Log.w(TAG, "Failed to stringify request body: " + e.getMessage());
      }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin version :

```
val buf = okio.Buffer()
requestBody.writeTo(buf)
Log.d("AppXMLPostReq", "reqBody = ${buf.readUtf8()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Separate new class and implement Intercepter.

```
  override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request: Request = chain.request()
        var logInfo = ""
        val requestBody=loggerUtil.getRequestBody
         return response
    }

yourOkHttpClient.addInterceptor(yourInstance)
```

GetRequestBody

```
            var requestContent = ""
            val requestBody = request.body
            val buffer = Buffer()
            if (requestBody != null) {
                requestBody.writeTo(buffer)
            }

            val contentType = requestBody?.contentType()
            val charset: Charset =
                contentType?.charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ?:StandardCharsets.UTF_8

            if (buffer.isProbablyUtf8()) {
                requestContent = buffer.readString(charset)
            }
```

Extension to find Whether buffer data is UT8 format

```
fun Buffer.isProbablyUtf8(): Boolean {
    try {
        val prefix = Buffer()
        val byteCount = size.coerceAtMost(64)
        copyTo(prefix, 0, byteCount)
        for (i in 0 until 16) {
            if (prefix.exhausted()) {
                break
            }
            val codePoint = prefix.readUtf8CodePoint()
            if (Character.isISOControl(codePoint) && !Character.isWhitespace(codePoint)) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    } catch (_: EOFException) {
        return false // Truncated UTF-8 sequence.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are we supposed to call .close() on the buffer object ? or use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement ?

```
private String getBodyAsString(Request request) throws IOException {
        try(var buffer = new Buffer()) {
            request.body().writeTo(buffer);
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        }
    }
```