# Intercept query strings

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I need to write a middleware for OKHttp to intercept all sended query parameters (`key1=value1&key2=value2&...`) and generate a digest according to the parameters and then put it on a specific header and send it along with the request, I can intercept all request through the following way:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();  
httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        String digest = "How can I get sended paramters?";

        Request request = original.newBuilder()
            .header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
            .header("Digest", digest)
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```

But I can't find a way to retrieve the list of parameters! any ideas?

Comment: why don't you compose the digest string while you're creating the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but I believe you can just do:

```
Request original = chain.request();
String params = original.url().query();
```

don't have an android environment to test this with at the moment though. If not look at the [okhttp javadoc](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/) for `Request` and `HttpUrl`

**EDIT**

for the post body there's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696964/okhttp-how-to-log-request-body) which I think does what you're after, but in a nutshell it's something like:

```
Request original = chain.request();
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
original.body().writeTo(buffer);
String bodyStr = buffer.readUtf8();
```

Comment: How about post values? is post values also supported?