# When sending okhttp request: HTTP ERROR 405 and invalid_client

Tags: java, https, oauth-2.0, request, okhttp

I'm making a request to a website. However, I keep getting a returned JSON of `{"error":"invalid_client"}`. Additionally, when I navigate to the URL I'm making the request to through a web browser it shows `HTTP ERROR 405`.

From what I read on those errors that might mean that my request isn't structured correctly.

According to the API's documentation, this is an example of the request type I'm trying to do:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "client_secret={your_client_secret}&client_id={your_client_id}&code={your_authorization_code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={your_redirect_uri}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://api.website.com/v2/oauth2/token")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

From what I can tell mine should be doing the same thing, just a little differently.

---

[Here](https://pastebin.com/224b7cxr) is a Pastebin of my `doInBackground` method (I'm using AsynchTask). Here is the more applicable part:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

// A section here gets strings from a JSON file storing values such as client_id

 RequestBody bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder()
  .add("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
  .add("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
  .add("code", AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
  .add("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE)
  .add("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI)
  .build();
 System.out.println("Built body: " + bodyBuilder.toString());

 String mediaTypeString = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(mediaTypeString);
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, requestbodyToString(bodyBuilder)); // See Edit 1

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(TARGET_URL)
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", mediaTypeString)
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

 try {
  System.out.println("Starting request.");
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  String targetUrl = request.url().toString() + bodyToString(request);
  System.out.println("request: " + targetUrl);
  String responseBodyString = response.body().string();
  System.out.println("response: " + responseBodyString);
  return responseBodyString;
 } catch (IOException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
 }
```

---

Like I said, I keep getting a returned JSON of `{"error":"invalid_client"}`, and when I navigate to the URL I'm making the request to through a web browser it shows `HTTP ERROR 405`.

---

I'd love to provide as much additional information as you need. Thanks!

---

Edit 1: The second parameter of this used to be "bodyBuilder.toString()", but I changed it because I realized it wasn't actually sending the body. The result is still the same - `{"error":"invalid_client"}`. The method now used comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30490779/7492795).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was - I hadn't actually been writing the `authentication_code` to the file, only adding it to another JSONObject. Oops. :)