# Accessing OKHttp Response Body

Tags: android, get, okhttp

So I need to figure out how to access the value I get from my first response in my second. I would think that I could just store it to a a variable and access it in another request. However, that does not seem to be the case.

Here is the bit that is giving me issues. So my first request is getting me a token and then I need to use that which is stored in commatoken in my second request.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken())
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }

                System.out.println(response.body().string());
                String commatoken = response.body().string();
            }
        });

        Request dataRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Authorization", "jwt"+commatoken)
                .url(ChffrMe_URL).build();

        client.newCall(dataRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }

                System.out.println(response.body().string());

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can call `response.body().string()` only once .... so save that data to a string variable first .. and access it wherever you need it.

```
String response_data;
..............
response_data = response.body().string();
```

You are calling **response.body().string()** twice ...

More info
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922818/3552066

Comment: Hmm even then the second comma token in the new Request is still red saying it cannot resolve symbol 'commatoken'

Comment: Declare commatoken at top ... make it global

Comment: Hmm for some reason the URL isn't accepting me putting that string value into the header...

Comment: Also, not sure if the second System.out.println is printing the value from the first request or second...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid about empty result:

```
assert response.body() != null;
String r = response.body().string();
```

And if you want access to each elements :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(r);
Log.i("love", "Res: "+json.getString("result")); //Name -> Answer
```

See the result:

```
{"fname":"John","sname":"Alice","percentage":"46","result":"Can choose someone better."} // String from 
I/love: Res: All the best! // Json form by Name
```